# Process description,user and publisher information in dump

Tags: windbg, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, crash-dumps

Is there a way to retrieve the process description and publisher from a Windows Kernel crash dump?

[image: Info in task manager]

[image: Info in task manager]

I tried [`!process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/hardware/ff564717(v=vs.85).aspx) and `!dml_proc`. It doesn't show that information.

Comment: doesn't lmvm of the said proceses 'file show you the company name . and file description as posted by pykd_team or me

Comment: `9: kd> lmvm "LPS GUI.exe"
start             end                 module name`

Comment: that means the image isn't fully available in your dump file did you do  reload /f  and set the process context you have to clutch at straws take a look at !vad_reload or at windbg help file for mapping symbols when peb is paged out documentation

Comment: @blabb I couldn't change the context. There is an error. Not sure how to work around it. I'm a Wintel engineer. Here is the output. https://jpst.it/Idsn

Comment: from your comment to an answer below if there are no active threads in the process then it could be very tedious to piece together stuff from this dump see if you can get a fresh dump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was trying to edit and post clarification to pykd-teams answer but the edit turned out ot be substantial so posted this as an answer

FileDescription from lmvm output refers to description column in Task manager Details tab

Company Name Refers refers to publisher column in startup tab

[image]

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic Startup where Caption="vmware user process" get /format:list    
Caption=VMware User Process
Command="C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools\vmtoolsd.exe" -n vmusr
Description=VMware User Process
Location=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Name=VMware User Process
SettingID=
User=Public
UserSID= 

C:\Windows\system32>reg query hklm\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run    
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run
    VMware User Process REG_SZ "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools\vmtoolsd.exe" -n vmusr
```

you can check by modifiying the FILE_VERSION_INFO in rsrc section of any file that is executed in startup see below an edited publisher in windbg of the same exe as posted above

how to check for validity of the above assertion

```
open a live kd session    
run task manager in target and select a startup     
look at details and locate the process name   say vmtoolsd.exe    
break into kd using ctrl+break     
!process 0 0 vmtoolsd.exe    
.process /p /r EPROCESS ADDRESS OF vmtoolsd.exe    
!dh vmtoolsd find the Data directory SECURITY DIRECTORY and start searching for FILE_VERSION_INFO   
loacte the string value of Company Name    
use eb Address to edit the Company Name to some random string    
execute using g    
now execute task manager and you will see the publisher column in startup tab reflecting the random string as publisher
```

[image]

```
username is not tied to file but to process grab the token     
from !process <Eproc> 1  and pass the TOKEN value to !token -n
```

here is sample script to retrieve user names for each running process

```
!for_each_process "r $t0=(@@c++(((_EPROCESS*) @#Process )->Token.Object)&0xfffffff8);r? $t1=@@c++(((_TOKEN*)@@(@$t0))->LogonSession->AccountName);r? $t2=@@c++(((_EPROCESS *) @#Process )->ImageFileName);.printf \"%mu\t\t\t%ma\\n\",@@c++((wchar_t *)@$t1.Buffer),@@c++((char*)@$t2)"
```

should get your results like this

```
kd> $$>a< getuname4proc.txt
xx-PC$          smss.exe

LOCAL SERVICE   svchost.exe

xx              taskhost.exe
```

Answer (score 4):

Description sould be get from exe module.
Example:

```
0: kd> !PROCESS fffffa800482f940 2
GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80397f65000
PROCESS fffffa800482f940
    SessionId: 1  Cid: 0e3c    Peb: 7f7cfefa000  ParentCid: 04bc
    DirBase: 26bcc000  ObjectTable: fffff8a0028f4e80  HandleCount: <Data Not Accessible>
    Image: Taskmgr.exe


0: kd> .process /p  fffffa800482f940
Implicit process is now fffffa80`0482f940
0: kd> .reload /user
Loading User Symbols
..........................................................
0: kd> lmvm Taskmgr
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
000007f7`d08c0000 000007f7`d09da000   taskmgr    (deferred)             
   Image path: C:\Windows\system32\taskmgr.exe
   Image name: taskmgr.exe
   Browse all global symbols  functions  data
   Timestamp:        Thu Jul 26 02:07:18 2012 (50107C26)
   CheckSum:         00119B41
   ImageSize:        0011A000
   File version:     6.2.9200.16384
   Product version:  6.2.9200.16384
   File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
   File OS:          40004 NT Win32
   File type:        1.0 App
   File date:        00000000.00000000
   Translations:     0409.04b0
   CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
   ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
   InternalName:     Taskmgr.exe
   OriginalFilename: Taskmgr.exe
   ProductVersion:   6.2.9200.16384
   FileVersion:      6.2.9200.16384 (win8_rtm.120725-1247)
   FileDescription:  Task Manager
   LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: The answer does not cover the user question yet.

Comment: @Thomas see my post as to why this answer covers the question

Comment: @blabb: Oh, it seems my comment was misleading. The question title says "Process description,user and publisher information in dump", so my assumption was that an answer would also cover information about how to get the content for Task Manager's "user name" column. The rest is ok and I actually upvoted this answer, because it is already useful.

Comment: @pykd_team I'm unable to change the context somehow.

`9: kd> !PROCESS fffffa8049eefa10
GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80001cb7000
PROCESS fffffa8049eefa10
    SessionId: 108  Cid: 50fc    Peb: 7efdf000  ParentCid: ea08
    DirBase: 20d763000  ObjectTable: fffff8a044733d00  HandleCount: 963.
    Image: LPS GUI.exe
    

No active threads`



`9: kd> .PROCESS /P fffffa8049eefa10
Couldn't resolve error at 'fffffa8049eefa10'`



`9: kd> lmvm "LPS GUI.exe"
start             end                 module name`


Removed some output of first command to meet comment size limitation.

Comment: @Thomas user name is process dependent you need the token for the process it is not retrievable from file  use !process @$proc 1 to see the token value and then pass it to !token -n

Comment: 2Ayan Mullick: It's seems "PROCESS fffffa8049eefa10" is a zombie.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information and a lot more by using `!ps` command from [DbgKit](http://www.andreybazhan.com/dbgkit.html).

**Note:** *From a Kernel Memory Dump you can only get User Name. To get User Name, File Description and Company Name you need a Complete Memory Dump.*

1. Copy `dbgkit.dll` into winext folder (For example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext`)
2. Open a dump file in WinDbg
3. Run `.load dbgkit` command
4. Run `!ps` command (to view other commands run !dbgkit.help)

[image: DbgKit - Process Explorer]

Comment: But isn't this just on a live system. I needed the User Name, File Description and Company Name of a process from a kernel dump.

Comment: From a Kernel Memory Dump you can only get User Name. To get User Name, File Description and Company Name you need a Complete Memory Dump.

Comment: I haven't used the Dbgkit before. Is there a step-by-step guide on how to load a dump for analysis. The screenshot just looks like Process explorer.

Comment: It's quite simple:
1. Copy dbgkit.dll into winext folder (For example: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext)
2. Open a dump file in WinDbg
3. Run .load dbgkit command
4. Run !ps command (to view other commands run !dbgkit.help)

Comment: @AndreyBazhan click on the **edit** button in your answer and here you can add new details. I did this now a 2nd time for you.